# Export GPG key from smartcard and import yubikey

Tags: gnupg, smartcard

I have the OPEN PGP SMARTCARD V2.1 and there I have a signature key, a encryption key and a authentication key stored. The last 8 digits of the signature key is for example: 1234 5678.
Now I want to copy these keys to my Yubikey Neo for backup purpose. I was trying this:

1. Plug in Smartcard and remove Yubikey
2. `gpg -a -o seckey.asc --export-secret-key 12456789`
3. Plug in Yubikey and remove Smartcard
4. `gpg --edit-key 12456789 - here I get: "Secret key is available"` and my keys are listed
5. toggle
   then:

   `gpg> keytocard
   Really move the primary key? (y/N) y
   Please select where to store the key:
      (1) Signature key
      (3) Authentication key
   Your selection? 1
   gpg: KEYTOCARD failed: Unusable secret key`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Secret keys cannot be exported from OpenPGP smart cards -- that's the very idea behind them. If you created the key on a computer and imported it to the smart card, use the backup to copy it to the Yubikey.

Otherwise, you'll have to create a new key. Be aware the Yubikey is *just another* OpenPGP smart card, so if you create the key directly on the Yubikey, you will not be able to export it, again.